# Error: Cannot find module './args'

Tags: node.js, npm

I had a project on my old mac that uses npm and node. When I replaced the computer, I copied the file into the new mac, and run `npm install` and then tried to run a script with browserify that will transpile the code for ES6. I keep getting the error

```
Error: Cannot find module './args'
```

which I assume is not a module. I've also tried to reinstall the major modules individually but the error continues.  Question: What does it mean when it says "cannot find module './args' and how do I fix that error?

```
 "scripts": {
    "build-js": "browserify app/app.js app/goopy.js app/models.js app/goofy.js -t babelify > app/bundle.js"
  },
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^5.0.3",
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^1.1.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6",
    "browserify": "latest",
    "watchify": "latest",
    "gulp": "latest",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "latest",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-qunit": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "JSON2": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "karma": "0.12.31",
    "qunit": "0.7.5",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.16",
    "sinon": "^1.12.2",
    "watchify": "^2.4.0"
  }
```

This is the full error message

```
Error: Cannot find module './args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mm/sites/backbone-seed/node_modules/.bin/browserify:6:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Update
Below is the output of running

```
find . -name \*.js -exec grep -H "\./args" {} \;
```

Note, based on the output below, I did `npm i` for `watchify`, `require` and `karma` but the error message remains

```
./node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js:var b = require('./args')(process.argv.slice(2));
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/elliptic/node_modules/hash.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/parse-asn1/node_modules/asn1.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/create-ecdh/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/create-ecdh/node_modules/elliptic/node_modules/hash.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/create-hash/node_modules/sha.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/diffie-hellman/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/public-encrypt/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/public-encrypt/node_modules/parse-asn1/node_modules/asn1.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/browserify/node_modules/shasum/node_modules/sha.js: Is a directory
./node_modules/karma/node_modules/http-proxy/node_modules/utile/lib/index.js:      return utile.args = require('./args');
./node_modules/watchify/bin/cmd.js:var fromArgs = require('./args.js');
./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js:var b = require('./args')(process.argv.slice(2));
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/elliptic/node_modules/hash.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/parse-asn1/node_modules/asn1.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/create-ecdh/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/create-ecdh/node_modules/elliptic/node_modules/hash.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/create-hash/node_modules/sha.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/diffie-hellman/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/public-encrypt/node_modules/bn.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/crypto-browserify/node_modules/public-encrypt/node_modules/parse-asn1/node_modules/asn1.js: Is a directory
grep: ./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/shasum/node_modules/sha.js: Is a directory
```

Comment: Search your project for require('./args') or require("./args"), is there anything calling that?

Comment: @YuriZarubin on a mac, I tried this `find . -type f -name "require('./args')"` in the project directory, no results

Comment: `find . -name \*.js -exec grep -H "\./args" {} \;` is what you probably want.

Comment: @avandeursen thanks, I printed the output to that command in the update to the OP

Comment: Glad it worked out. Adding your `-type f` should remove all the directory warnings from the output.

Comment: @avandeursen can you explain why ` {} \;` was necessary on the end?

Comment: From `man find`, under `-exec`: Expression after `-exec` must be terminated by a `;` -- which when entered in the shell must be escaped by a \. If the string `{}` appears between `-exec` and `;`, it is replaced by the pathname of the file `find` found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@avandeursen suggested that I run this command

```
find . -name \*.js -exec grep -H "\./args" {} \;
```

to locate the require('/args') code in the project, and based on the output in the update to the OP, i reinstalled browserify `npm i browserify` and now the error message is gone.

Comment: I ran into this issue after I copied my `node_modules` folder into a different project. Similar to your solution, killing `node_modules` and re-installing fixed for me.

Answer (score 2):

When you copy a project is better to start with a clean installation for your dependencies:

1. Delete directory

   ```
   /node_modules/
   ```
2. Type in your terminal

   ```
   npm install
   ```
3. Run your code

Comment: i did this and i got error cant find module "semver"